# Transact SQL field pattern

Tags: t-sql

I am learning `transact SQL`. While I am creating table I want to have only two possibilities to input: M - for men, W - for women.

I fount example at this [address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms190377(v=sql.110).aspx). I was using `posgresql` before and its really simple to set pattern there.

This is what have i tried:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable (
      sex char(1) LIKE '[M]' OR '[W]',
)
```

I am getting this error message: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link you provided, you can create a `Constraint` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable (sex char(1));
ALTER TABLE testTable ADD CONSTRAINT chk_Sex CHECK (sex IN ('M','W'));
```

Or you can do it in one statement:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable (sex char(1), CONSTRAINT chk_sex CHECK (sex IN ('M','W')))
```

Or even:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable (sex char(1) CHECK (sex IN ('M','W')))
```

Comment: or `CREATE TABLE testTable (sex char(1) CHECK (sex IN ('M','W')))`

Comment: Whats about numeric type?  Now I want to input only three number. I have used some part of the example from link.

I have created this:
`constraint cbk_sex check ( sex in ('[0-9][0-9][0-9]'))`

Of course I have changed size of char to (14). I can create without any errors, but when I want to execute ` insert into testtable (sex) VALUES(213)` I am getting 

`The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "cbsk_sex". The conflict occurred in database "biblioteka", table "dbo.testtable", column 'sex'.
` error. Any ideas?

Comment: a three digit number? sex between 0 and 999

Comment: Briefly, looks like you have a type mismatch. If you have another question that you cannot find a similar solution to on StackOverflow, please post it as a new question instead of hiding it in the comments section here- it's better for the community.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE testTable
(
   sex CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT check_sex CHECK (sex IN ('M', 'W'))
)
```