# SQL Server field pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Based on this [addres](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms190377(v=sql.110).aspx) and my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47562605/transact-sql-field-pattern) I tried this time to make 
3 numbers input coercion. So I have table with field called `inputNumbers varchar(5)`.
I official documentation is `'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'` syntax. Its for column that is 5 digit lenght.

```
inputNumbers varchar(5),
constraint check_numbers check ( inputNumbers in ('[0-9][0-9][0-9]'))
```

The table was created without any error messages, but when I executing `insert into testtable(inputNumbers) VALUES(213)` command it returns error

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "check_numbers". The conflict occurred in database "master", table "dbo.testtable", column 'inputNumbers'.

I need to mention that I asked for it in my previous question, but I have marked the post as solved before I thought about this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to incorrect constraint `check_numbers` defined correct as follow

```
constraint check_numbers check ( inputNumbers like ('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'))
```

Comment: The wildcards will let this pattern match `"My number is 666, what's yours?"`. That doesn't sound like the OP's intent.